# Allow iteration of an internal vector without leaking the implementation

Tags: c++

I have a class that represents a list of people.

```
class AddressBook
{
public:
  AddressBook();

private:
  std::vector<People> people;
}
```

I want to allow clients to iterate over the vector of people. The first thought I had was simply:

```
std::vector<People> & getPeople { return people; }
```

However, *I do not want to leak the implementation details to the client*. I may want to maintain certain invariants when the vector is modified, and I lose control over these invariants when I leak the implementation.

What's the best way to allow iteration without leaking the internals?

Comment: First of all, if you want to maintain control, you should return your vector as a const reference. You'd still expose implementation details that way, so I recommend making your class iterable and never exposing your data structure (maybe it will be a hash table tomorrow?).

Comment: A quick google search revealed me this example: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/Iterator/cpp/1

Comment: What @DocBrown says is likely the appropriate solution - in practice this means you give your AddressBook class a begin() and end() method (plus const overloads and eventually also cbegin/cend) which simply return the vector's begin() and end(). By doing so your class will also be usable by all most std algorythms.

Comment: @stijn That should be an answer, not a comment :-)

Comment: @stijn No, that is not what DocBrown and the linked article says. The correct solution is to use a proxy class pointing to the container class along with a safe mechanism for indicating position. Returning the vector's `begin()` and `end()` are dangerous because (1) those types are vector iterators (classes) which prevents one from switching to another container such as a `set`. (2) If the vector is modified (e.g. grown or some items erased), some or all of the vector iterators could have been invalidated.

Comment: @rwong good points indeed - I reckon my solution is maybe too simplistic. Yet, for 1) I'm probaby used to using `auto` unless it's not possible, a mechanism which makes one way less dependent of actual iterator type and 2) that is a design decision made and hence has to be documented anyway - sure using vector is dangerous because it's iterators can be invalidated but it's not like that makes vector unusable. Though depending on the exact usage which the OP doesn't mention set/list/... might indeed be a better choice here.

Comment: @stijn I agree that OP needs to articulate clearer ideas about what implementation or design changes need to be *reserved* before one can offer suggestions on how to properly guard against those changes. As C++ always favors efficiency over abstraction (decoupling), and puts correctness on the shoulder of the user of an API, exposing `const std::vector<T>&` might be the most idiomatic way in C++.

Comment: One should not prematurely pessimize.  Strong hiding of implementation details can slow access by multiples, and add to design complexity.  "I want to hide" -- what do you want to hide, why, and how strongly?  What invariants?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*allow iteration without leaking the internals* is exactly what the iterator pattern promises. Of course that is mainly theory so here is a practical example:

```
class AddressBook
{
  using peoples_t = std::vector<People>;
public:
  using iterator = peoples_t::iterator;
  using const_iterator = peoples_t::const_iterator;

  AddressBook();

  iterator begin() { return people.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return people.end(); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return people.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return people.end(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const { return people.cbegin(); }
  const_iterator cend() const { return people.cend(); }

private:
  peoples_t people;
};
```

You provide standard `begin` and `end` methods, just like sequences in the STL and implement them simply by forwarding to vector's method. This does leak *some* implementation detail namely that you're returning a vector iterator but no sane client should ever depend on that so it is imo not a concern. I've shown all overloads here but of course you can start by just providing the const version if clients should not be able to change any People entries. Using the standard naming has benefits: anyone reading the code immediately knows it provides 'standard' iteration and as such works with all common algorithms, range based for loops etc.

Comment: note: though this certainly works and is accepted it's worth taking note of rwong's comments to the question: adding an extra wrapper/proxy around vector's iterators here would make clients independent of the actual underlying iterator

Comment: In addition, note that providing a `begin()` and `end()` that just forward to the vector's `begin()` and `end()` allows the user to modify the elements in the vector itself, maybe using `std::sort()`.  Depending on what invariants you are trying to preserve, this may or may not be acceptable.  Providing `begin()` and `end()`, though, is necessary to support the C++11 range-based for loops.

Comment: You should probably also show the same code using auto as return types of iterator functions when using C++14.

Comment: How is this hiding the implementation details?

Comment: @BЈовић by not exposing the complete vector - *hiding* does not necessarily mean the implementation has to be literally hidden from a header and put in the source file: if it's private client cannot access it anyway

Answer (score 8):

If iteration is all you need, then perhaps a wrapper around `std::for_each` would suffice:

```
class AddressBook
{
public:
  AddressBook();

  template <class F>
  void for_each(F f) const
  {
    std::for_each(begin(people), end(people), f);
  }

private:
  std::vector<People> people;
};
```

Comment: It would probably better to enforce a const iteration with cbegin/cend. But that solution is by far better than giving access to the underlying container.

Comment: @galop1n It *does* enforce a `const` iteration. The `for_each()` is a `const` member function. Hence, the member `people` is seen as `const`. Hence, `begin()` and `end()` will overload as `const`. Hence, they will return `const_iterator`s to `people`. Hence, `f()` will receive a `People const&`. Writing `cbegin()`/`cend()` here will change nothing, in practice, though as an obsessive user of `const` I might argue it's still worth doing, as (a) why not; it's just 2 chars, (b) I like saying what I mean, at least with `const`, (c) it guards against accidentally pasting somewhere non-`const`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), and provide methods to iterate over the container.

In the header :

```
typedef People* PeopleIt;

class AddressBook
{
public:
  AddressBook();


  PeopleIt begin();
  PeopleIt begin() const;
  PeopleIt end();
  PeopleIt end() const;

private:
  struct Imp;
  std::unique_ptr<Imp> pimpl;
};
```

In the source :

```
struct AddressBook::Imp
{
  std::vector<People> people;
};

PeopleIt AddressBook::begin()
{
  return &pimpl->people[0];
}
```

This way, if your client uses the typedef from the header, they will not notice what kind of container you are using. And the implementation details are completely hidden.

Comment: This is CORRECT...complete implementation hiding and no additional overhead.

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. "_no additional overhead_" is plainly false. PImpl adds a dynamic memory allocation (and, later, free) for every instance, and a pointer indirection (at least 1) for every method that goes through it. Whether that is *much* overhead for any given situation depends on benchmarking/profiling, and in many cases it's probably perfectly fine, but it is absolutely not true - and I think rather irresponsible - to proclaim that it has **no** overhead.

Comment: @underscore_d I agree; not meaning to be irresponsible there, but, I guess that I fell prey to the context. “No additional overhead...” is technically incorrect, as you deftly pointed out; apologies...

Comment: So end() would return the last element and not one beyond the last element, right?
In that case, calling it for example last() instead of end() might be better.

Answer (score 1):

if you want exact implementation of functions from std::vector, use private inheritance as below and control what is exposed.

```
template <typename T>
class myvec : private std::vector<T>
{
public:
    using std::vector<T>::begin;
    using std::vector<T>::end;
    using std::vector<T>::push_back;
};
```

Edit:
 This is not recomended if you also want to hide internal data structure i.e. std::vector

Comment: Inheritance in such a situation is at best very lazy (you should use composition and provide forwarding methods, especially since there are so few to forward here), often confusing and inconvenient (what if you want to add your own methods that conflict with `vector` ones, which you never want to use but nonetheless must inherit?), and maybe actively dangerous (what if the class being lazily inherited from might be deleted through a pointer to that base type somewhere, but it [irresponsibly] didn't protect against destruction of a derived obj via such a pointer, so simply destroying it is UB?)

Answer (score 0):

One could provide member functions:

```
size_t Count() const
People& Get(size_t i)
```

Which allow access without exposing implementation details (like contiguity) and use these within an iterator class:

```
class Iterator
{
    AddressBook* addressBook_;
    size_t index_;

public:
    Iterator(AddressBook& addressBook, size_t index=0) 
    : addressBook_(&addressBook), index_(index) {}

    People& operator*()
    {
        return addressBook_->Get(index_);
    }

    Iterator& operator ++ ()
    {
       ++index_;
       return *this;
    }

    bool operator != (const Iterator& i) const
    {
        assert(addressBook_ == i.addressBook_);
        return index_ != i.index_;
    }
};
```

Iterators can then be returned by the address book as follows:

```
AddressBook::Iterator AddressBook::begin()
{
    return Iterator(this);
}

AddressBook::Iterator AddressBook::end()
{
    return Iterator(this, Count());
}
```

You'd probably need to flesh the iterator class out with traits etc but I think that this will do what you've asked.